# (Ubuntu Server 20.04) Connecting Two Servers Together Through Network Switch

Tags: networking, server, ssh, network-manager, internet

I am trying to connect two servers together through a network switch. I've tried researching this, but all of the good examples are from the pre-'network manager' era.

So, my setup consists of two nearly identical Ubuntu 20.04 servers with an unmanaged network switch connecting them.

I've assigned them IP addresses, 192.168.4.123/24 and 192.168.2.123/24.

I wasn't entirely sure what to put for the default gateway because this is supposed to be a peer-to-peer connection, but I read that 0.0.0.0 is a catch-all, however, if I use 0.0.0.0 I lose ethernet on all interfaces for some reason. Maybe I am not editing the default gateway correctly.

I try to ping the other server, 192.168.x.123, and receive nothing. I am sure there is something stupid I'm overlooking, but can't seem to find it.

Picture of the network configuration...

[image: Picture of Network Setup with central Network Switch connecting both servers]

Anyways, this topic seems worthy of a tutorial in a blog or something.

Pardon me if there is any etiquette to these posts, I've never posted on StackExchange before.

Edit:

```
ip addr show results:


5: eno2np1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:97:e1:bc:df:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.3/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global eno2np1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::be97:e1ff:febc:df87/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

0.0.0.0         10.3.13.253     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 

eno1np0
10.3.12.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U         0 0          0 eno1np0
10.3.13.253     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno1np0
10.233.170.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 lxdbr0
10.244.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 cni0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eno2np1
    netstat -r -n results:
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
    0.0.0.0         10.3.13.253     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eno1np0
    10.3.12.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U         0 0          0 eno1np0
    10.3.13.253     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno1np0
    192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eno2np1
    192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 virbr0

From Server B:

4: eno2np1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:97:e1:bc:9f:67 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.2/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global eno2np1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::be97:e1ff:febc:9f67/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.3.13.253     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eno1np0
10.3.12.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U         0 0          0 eno1np0
10.3.13.253     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno1np0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eno2np1
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 virbr0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is absolutely basic networking (not Linux) knowledge.

You wrongly put your servers on different subnets. If they are connected via a switch, it is a layer 2 connection, so they must be in the same subnet. You would be using different subnets if there were a router instead of a switch (layer 3 connection). In that case you would also need appropriate routes on each server.

Change one of the addresses so that they are in the same subnet. For example change the address of first server from 192.168.4.123/24 to 192.168.2.124/24.

Do not put anything as default gateway because you don't have any default gateway on this network. Default gateway is a router that connects your subnet to any external network (ie. other than the networks already specified in explicit routes). This subnet does not connect to any external networks, so it does not have a default gateway.

Comment: Destination Host Unreachable after pinging to test. Is there something else that is commonly overlooked?

Comment: This is strange. Can you again post IP addresses, netmasks (`ip addr show`) and routing tables (`netstat -r -n`) of both servers after change?

Comment: Please also post the same from the other server.

Comment: it should be there now.

Comment: It is still wrong. You set up **two identical IP addresses** (192.168.2.3) on both servers. You must have different addresses, but in the same subnet. Change address of server B for example to 192.168.2.4

Comment: Sorry, I was playing around with it and forget to edit the second one. I've tried it out with different IP addresses, you can trust me. I just updated the netplan to fix that.

Comment: Okay, so I've fixed the output from the commands now. Still 
From 192.168.2.2 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

Comment: With this setup, ping from 192.168.2.3 to 192.168.2.2 (or vice versa) should work. Is the physical connection OK? Is it a managed or unmanaged switch? If managed, are both ports you connected the servers to on the same VLAN? Do you have any firewall rules activated on any of the servers? If yes, disable the firewall and try again.

Comment: The switch I am using, the Intellinet 530378 apparently is unmanaged. It has auto-network discovery, it automatically configures itself. The details are probably in the standards documents.

Comment: Yes, looks like a simple unmanaged switch. So the problem is either in the physical connection or in the firewall. I don't see any other possibility.

Comment: Cat6e cables will work?

Comment: Yes, they should work. Are the LEDs on the switch and on the network cards in the servers OK? Do you have the `ethtool` installed? If not, try to install it and check the connection state it shows for your `eno2np1`. And what about the firewall rules?

Comment: Raj, I got a new unmanaged switch and it seems to work. Your steps were all correct, I just had some faulty Switch. Traded the Intellinet Switch for a D-Link Switch.